# SQL Compare rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, compare

Okay here is the situation:
I the following data in a table.

```
PAIR_NO NO          NO2

3       5678EFGH    1234ABCD
4       1111BBBB    0000AAAA
1       1234ABCD    5678EFGH
2       0000AAAA    1111BBBB
```

The constraints are if no = no2 in another row skip that row.
So in this sample data the only rows that would be selected should be pair no 3 and 4.

I have tried to merge and inner join with self but I just keep getting all 4 rows back.

I have tried to insert into a table where not exists but again I get 4 rows inserted.

```
   SELECT a.* from PAIRS a
   inner join PAIRS b on a.no=b.no2 and a.no2=b.no;
```

I was thinking maybe selecting distinct number from column 1 and then check those in column 2 but I think that would yield the same four rows.

I may be over thinking this problem and maybe some here can look at this and see where the solution is hiding.

I am currently testing this on MySQL but it should run on SQLServer 2008. I have searched but all the questions didn't seem to match my data set issue.

Comment: Note: For all 4 rows you have presented there is a match between `NO` and `NO2` in any other row. I don't know how you think pairs 3 and 4 should only be selected.

Comment: If I were doing this in C# I would create a holding object for the rows.

Comment: If I were doing this in C# I would create a holding object for the rows. Then as I am looping each row, test - does column 1 match column 2 in the holding object. If it does not exist then add to the holding object. But I need to try and recreate this in SQL and I am trying to avoid using WHILE loop (just too slow when I am process more records).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay fellas I want to thank you all for helping, but I think I solved my issue. Took me a second but I believe this is what I am after (SQL Server 2008):

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pairs') is not null drop table #pairs 
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pairs_final') is not null drop table #pairs_final
create table #pairs(pair_no int, a_no varchar(17),a_no2 varchar(17))
create table #pairs_final(pair_no int Identity(1,1), a_no varchar(17),a_no2 varchar(17))


insert into #PAIRS values(1,'1234ABCD','5678EFGH');
insert into #PAIRS values(1,'1234ABCD','XXXX9999');
insert into #PAIRS values(2,'0000AAAA','1111BBBB');
insert into #PAIRS values(3,'5678EFGH','1234ABCD');
insert into #PAIRS values(4,'1111BBBB','0000AAAA');
insert into #PAIRS values(1,'XXXX9999','1234ABCD');

insert into #pairs_final
select a.a_no,a.a_no2 from #pairs a
    join (
        select distinct a_no_p from(
            select pair_no,a_no_p,
            ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by pair_no order by a_no_p) as RN
            from #pairs
            unpivot(
                 a_no_p for clms in (a_no2,a_no)
            ) as umpvt
        ) as mypairs
        where RN = 1
     ) as my_pairs on my_pairs.a_no_p=a.a_no

select * from #pairs_final
```

This will give me the following results:

```
pair_no  a_no       a_no2
1        1234ABCD   5678EFGH
2        1234ABCD   XXXX9999
3        0000AAAA   1111BBBB
```

Hope this might help someone else.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Taking you at your word, meaning selecting all records where the value of `no` column does not appear anywhere in `no2` column in the same table, try this:

```
SELECT A.PAIR_NO, A.NO, A.NO2
FROM PAIRS A 
LEFT JOIN PAIRS B ON(A.NO = B.NO2)
WHERE B.PAIR_NO IS NULL -- assuming this column is not nullable
```

Another option is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT PAIR_NO, NO, NO2
FROM PAIRS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM PAIRS B
    WHERE B.NO2 = A.NO
)
```

I personally prefer the LEFT JOIN option since it's shorter and more readable.
Both of these statement should work on both MySql and Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TBL AS TABLE
(
[NO] INT,
[CODE] VARCHAR(50),
[AREA] VARCHAR(50)
)

/* EXAMPLE 1 */
INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES (1,'001','A00')
INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES (2,'001','A00')
INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES (3,'001','B00')
INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES (4,'001','C00')
INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES (5,'001','C00')
INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES (6,'001','A00')
INSERT INTO @TBL([NO],[CODE],[AREA]) VALUES (7,'001','A00')

/* EXAMPLE 2 */
/* ***** USE THIS CODE TO ENTER DATA FROM DIRECT TABLE *****
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [FIELD_DATE]) AS [NO]
,[FIELD_CODE] AS [CODE]
,[FIELD_AREA] AS [AREA]
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE CAST([FIELD_DATE] AS DATE) >= CAST('20200307' AS DATE)
ORDER BY [FIELD_DATE],[FIELD_CODE]
*/

SELECT
A.NO AS ANO
,A.CODE AS ACODE
,A.AREA AS AAREA
,B.NO AS BNO
,B.CODE AS BCODE
,B.AREA AS BAREA
,CASE WHEN A.AREA=B.AREA THEN 'EQUAL' ELSE 'NOT EQUAL' END AS [COMPARE AREA]
FROM @TBL A
LEFT JOIN @TBL B
ON A.NO=B.NO+1
```